# Trouble with Vue3 and vuedraggable: Unable to Drag Elements Between Outermost Layers

Tags: vuejs3, vuedraggable

I want to drag an element between the outermost elements, but I can't seem to do it successfully. There's only one specific and small spot where I accidentally discovered I can drag it successfully.

**[Code sandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-kilby-stmvgj?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog000a3b6iju028ohw%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztjloe005t3b6iijmdbtp4%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00073b6imstefydf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00093b6i943sz3u8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cloztiuog00093b6i943sz3u8%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00083b6ico7oaxi3%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00093b6i943sz3u8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00083b6ico7oaxi3%2522%257D%252C%2522cloztiuog00073b6imstefydf%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00073b6imstefydf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clozuh7hs03jc3b6ivhoiifiq%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztiuog00053b6ik6f3pb68%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztp4ql00rj3b6imnbe0flq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cloztp4uu00cqeed96r95d3vg%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozuh7hs03jc3b6ivhoiifiq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cloztjloe005t3b6iijmdbtp4%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztjloe005t3b6iijmdbtp4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clozukrgj05lj3b6i1u1e9a7a%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Frouter%252Findex.js%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztroai015w3b6id2mblvxs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FRow.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloztticx01tw3b6ihzp2neg2%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FColumn.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozu0qy7022y3b6ie3smqbeh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FSection.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozu43ak02hs3b6ihq4uhzyb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fviews%252FHomeView.vue%2520%28DELETED%29%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozu5am502n43b6ipo4vkntf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fmain.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozuketf05ha3b6icvmgizwk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozukrgj05lj3b6i1u1e9a7a%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FNestedDraggable.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozuurho07pp3b6igqxq7cep%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fdata.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clozv3xmc07z93b6ixbyozsmo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)**

[image: Target]

[image: GIF demo]

Core code fragment

```js
<template>
  <draggable
    :list="data.children || []"
    :group="{ name: 'nested' }"
    :tag="handleTag(data.type)"
    itemKey="id"
    ghostClass="ghost"
    :swapThreshold="0.1"
    :fallbackOnBody="true"
    :animation="150"
    direction="vertical"
    :emptyInsertThreshold="10"
  >
    <template #item="{ element }">
      <button v-if="element.type === 'button'">button</button>
      <div v-else-if="element.type === 'text'">some text</div>
      <NestedDraggable v-else :data="element" />
    </template>
  </draggable>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

interface Props {
  data: { id: string; type: string; group: string; children: any[] };
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {});

const handleTag = (type: string | undefined) => {
  if (!type) return "div";

  switch (type) {
    case "section": {
      return "Section";
    }
    case "row": {
      return "Row";
    }
    case "column": {
      return "Column";
    }
    default: {
      return type;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I expect it to be dragged to the target position correctly.

I've researched and tried modifying vuedraggable parameters (`swapThreshold`, `invertSwap`, `emptyInsertThreshold`), and also adjusted the spacing between elements, but haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

I have a complex nesting requirement, and I've been struggling with a strange issue for two days. I hope someone can provide a solution. Thank you!